# SQL Query to AfterEvent Function

Tags: sql, ms-access, combobox

Hope your all well.

You might have seen one of my previously related posts in which I was asking for some help with multiple columns in a combo box. We'll I solved that through concatenating the Salutation, FirstName and LastName fields, to give one whole field to run from, which saved me a heap of time. I am however struggling to get what looks like a straight forward SQL statement to work.

My SQL statement is as follows;

```
SELECT LocalAuthority.LocalAuthorityName, Contacts.ContactFullName
FROM LocalAuthority, Contacts
WHERE (((LocalAuthority.RequestType)=[Forms]![Requests]![cboRequestType])) 
       OR    (((Contacts.RequestType)=[Forms]![Requests]![cboRequestType]))
ORDER BY LocalAuthority.LocalAuthorityName, Contacts.ContactFullName;
```

This dosen't work, however this does work when I only use Local Authority as the field source in the query. I do have the Request Type field in the Contacts table as a combo box linked to a query, but that shouldn't have to much of an effect, should it?

All help greatly appreciated!

Best,

Will

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, that query doesn't define how the **LocalAuthority** and **Contacts** tables are linked, where is the join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you need a union query:

```
SELECT ContactName FROM (
   SELECT RequestType, LocalAuthorityName As ContactName 
   FROM LocalAuthority
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT RequestType, ContactFullName As ContactName 
   FROM Contacts) d
WHERE d.RequestType = [Forms]![Requests]![cboRequestType]
ORDER BY d.ContactName
```

If you need to know which table, you can say:

```
SELECT ContactName FROM (
   SELECT "Auth" As TFrom, RequestType, LocalAuthorityName As ContactName 
   FROM LocalAuthority
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT "Contact" As TFrom, RequestType, ContactFullName As ContactName 
   FROM Contacts) d
WHERE d.RequestType = [Forms]![Requests]![cboRequestType]
ORDER BY d.ContactName
```

UNION ALL is faster, but will include duplicates, UNION is slow, but only includes unique rows.

Comment: +1 The question isn't all that clear from the sample SQL, but I'm leaning towards a Union query also.